# Year over Year by Month Comparison and Month to Date in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Edit: @shawnt00 has the correct answer. Thank you very much!

I am having trouble accurately doing a year over year comparison by month but at any point during the month. For example for August 2022 vs 2021, I want to compare August 1 - August 25, rather than full month of August 2021.

I am also using a daily date field.

I want the final result to basically be:

Product_ID, Year, Month, PY_Sales, CY_Sales

Edit: I have daily totals. Some products do have not sales on certain days though:

| product_id | sale_date | units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 2021-06-05 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-01-06 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-08-15 | 9 |

This is the code I have, but it doesn't do MTD. So 2021 August is the entire month of August and I want it the same dates for 2022. I used this code because some products do not have sales on certain months.

```
    WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT 
     PRODUCT_ID,
     EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SALE_DATE) AS Year,
     EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SALE_DATE) AS Month,
     CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SALE_DATE), '-',EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SALE_DATE)) AS Year_Month,
     SUM(Units) AS Units
FROM data
WHERE Product_ID = 1
AND DATE(SALE_DATE) >= '2019-01-01'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
),

    diff AS 
( 
SELECT 
     COALESCE(c.PRODUCT_ID, p.PRODUCT_ID) AS Product_ID,
     COALESCE(c.Year, p.Year + 1) AS Year,
     COALESCE(c.Month, p.Month) AS Month,
     IFNULL(c.Units, 0) AS Current_Units,
     IFNULL(p.Units, 0) AS Previous_Units,
     NULLIF(((IFNULL(c.Units, 0) - IFNULL(p.Units,0)) / p.Units),0) * 100 AS Percent_Change
FROM CTE c
FULL OUTER JOIN CTE p ON c.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID AND c.Year = p.Year + 1 AND c.Month = p.Month
WHERE c.Year <= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE())
ORDER BY 2, c.Year, c.Month
)
SELECT *
FROM diff
--This is to avoid dividing by 0
WHERE diff.Previous_Units > 0
--AND Percent_Change <= -.5
```

Comment: can you please supülay a [mre] see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What should it do on the last day of February when the prior year was a leap year?

Comment: if your "months" are not standard calendar units then you need a table with the definition of each user defined period, the design of this should provide some attribute that allows alignment of the same period in each year e.g. a period number from 1 to 12 (or 1 to 13 if using 13 periods a year).

Comment: Are you looking to prorate the YOY data for current month? Does you have daily totals available?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @shawnt00 No I am not looking to prorate. Just monthly totals for both years. But for the current month like August 2022, I want to compare MTD 2022 with the same days in 2021.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Added more info and the current code I have.

Answer (score 1):

You could just roll up two different monthly totals and then switch for the current month comparison:

```
with agg as (
    select
        PRODUCT_ID,
        extract(year from SALE_DATE) as yr,
        extract(month from SALE_DATE) as mth,
        sum(Units) as Units,
        sum(case when extract(day from SALE_DATE) <= extract(day from current_date())
                 then Units end) as UnitsMTD
    from data
    where date(SALE_DATE) >= '2019-01-01' -- one year before report output
    group by 1, 2, 3
)
select c.Yr, c.Mth, c.PRODUCT_ID,
    case when Yr  = extract(year  from current_date())
          and Mth = extract(month from current_date())
         then (c.UnitsMTD - p.UnitsMTD) / p.UnitsMTD
         else (c.Units    - p.Units   ) / p.Units
    end as Percent_Change
from agg c left outer join agg p
    on p.Product_ID = c.Product_ID and p.Yr = c.Yr - 1 and p.Mth = c.Mth
order by c.Yr, c.Mth, c.PRODUCT_ID;
```

Note my earlier comment about leap years. This will treat February 28 of the year following a leap year as an "MTD" month. You might need to handle that differently inside the `case` expression.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work actually. The previous months do not match up

Comment: @somequestionsforu I wrote it as a left join while you had a full join. Since I'm not really sure what the data looks like or how you want this to work you'll have to be a little more specific about that.